# How to pass a function to transcluded scope from a controller (angular 1.3)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I created a simple reusable collection container as a directive with an isolated scope an a `transclude` option is set to true.

```
app.directive('itemWrapper', function() {
  return {
    template: '...',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '=',
      isExpanded: '='
    }
  };
```

});

and a list view directive, where I'd like to pass a function from the controller that will handle clicks on list items

```
app.directive('listItem', function() {
      return {
        template: '...',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          item: '=',
          action: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
          scope.performAction = function(val){
            action({'data': val});
          };
        }
      };
});
```

my chunk of html looks in a following way:

```
<collection-wrapper name='item.name' is-expanded='item.visible'>
  <list-item item='item' action='log(data)'></list-item>
</collection-wrapper>
```

But when I click the link I get a Reference Error, saying that `action` is not defined. The question is, how to pass a function to this directive from a controller? As I understand, transcluded scope is a child of isolated scope and this is an obstacle I couldn't get over!

Here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aNhslp3fUXTV7l8NlRUL?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action` is a method on the scope. You need to say:

```
scope.action({'data': val});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gt6BgCpZ9qmOEJ8yS4UD?p=preview

Comment: Damn... I omit 'scope' in the directives all the time without a reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to you , "to pass the function  from controller  means to initiate the function from the controller or you wan the function to be triggered from inside the transcluded content??

Comment: To call a function inside the transcluded content.

Comment: The methodology u have used  to assign the reference of the method inside the directive is absolutely perfect , but since the reference is assigned to the isolated scope variable, **"scope"** has to be prefixed along the method during the call initiation..

**"scope.action({'data':val});"**             

I suppose this would work fine...!!    cheers.

Check out [this link](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html) to know further about it..